# Is the set of Borel measurable transformations the closure of continuous functions under pointwise limits?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, borel-sets, measurable-functions

If $S$ and $T$ are topological spaces, then $f:S\rightarrow T$ is called a Borel-measurable transformation if for every Borel set $B$ in $T$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set in $S$.  My question is, is the set of Borel-measurable transformations from $S$ to $T$ equal to the smallest set containing the continuous functions from $S$ to $T$ and closed under pointwise limits of functions?

I know this is true if $S=T=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, but I was wondering if it’s true in general.  It would certainly make sense if it were true in general.

Comment: I know it is true if $S$ is any metric space and $T=\mathbb{R}$. The proof is not trivial though. Not sure about general topological spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails badly when $T\neq \mathbb{R}$. For an example (lifted from *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Kechris, Section 24.B), consider the functions $\mathbb{R}\to \{0,1\}$, where the latter has the discrete topology. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, the only continuous functions are constant, and the set of constant functions is closed under pointwise limits. But there are many more Borel functions: the characteristic function of every Borel set is a Borel function $\mathbb{R}\to \{0,1\}$.

---

The statement is true in the following two cases:

- $S$ and $T$ are separable and metrizable, and $T = \mathbb{R}$.
- $S$ and $T$ are separable and metrizable, and $S$ is zero-dimensional.

No doubt there are other situations in which it holds, but these are the cases covered in Chapter 24 of Kechris's book.

More precisely, suppose $S$ and $T$ are metrizable and $T$ is separable. Then:

- Let $\Gamma$ be a set of subsets of $S$. We say that a function $f$ is **$\Gamma$-measurable** if $f^{-1}(U)\in \Gamma$ for every open set $U\subseteq T$. Let $\mathcal{F}(\Gamma)$ be the set of all $\Gamma$-measurable functions $S\to T$.
- We say that a function $S\to T$ is **Baire class $1$** if it is $\Sigma^0_2$-measurable. For any ordinal $1<\alpha<\omega_1$, we say that a function is **Baire class $\alpha$** if it is a pointwise limit of a sequence of functions of Baire class $<\alpha$. Let $\mathcal{B}_\alpha$ be the set of functions $S\to T$ of Baire class $\alpha$.

Then the theorem (24.3 in Kechris) is that a function $f\colon S\to T$ is Baire class $\alpha$ if and only if it is $\Sigma^0_{\alpha+1}$-measurable, i.e. $\mathcal{B}_\alpha = \mathcal{F}(\Sigma^0_{\alpha+1})$.

Now $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}B_\alpha$ is the smallest set of functions containing the containing the Baire class $1$ functions and closed under pointwise limits of sequences. And $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1} \mathcal{F}(\Sigma^0_{\alpha})$ is the set of all Borel-measurable functions $S\to T$. So we conclude that the set of Borel-measurable functions is the smallest set of functions containing the Baire class $1$ functions and closed under pointwise limits of sequences.

But your question was about the smallest set of functions containing the *continuous* functions and closed under pointwise limits of sequences. Why didn't we define Baire class $0$ to be the continuous functions and Baire class $1$ to be the set of pointwise limits of sequences of continuous functions?

Because it's exactly here in the "base case" that things go wrong. We need  hypotheses on $S$ and $T$, like those stated at the top, to prove that a function is $\Sigma^0_2$ measurable if and only if it is a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions (see 24.10 in Kechris). This is the statement that fails in the example when $T = \{0,1\}$.